# Bootstrap 3 nav collapse menu - anchor always on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this Bootstrap head menu, and i want the Login anchor, allways on the right, after the UL nav, and collapsed button.

I've tried a .pull-right on that, but didn't work.

```
    <header id="main-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                    class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Logo" src=""></a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                <li><a href="~/Home">home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">link3</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">link4</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">link4</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>sublink</li>
                    <li>sublink2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Login</a></div>

    </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there's problem with `jsfiddle` currently, I'll paste modified code here:

```
<header id="main-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="pull-right">
                <a id="rightAnchor" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Login</a>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>                 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Logo" src=""/></a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="~/Home">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">link2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">link3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">link4</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>sublink</li>
                            <li>sublink2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Firsltly, you're missing one closing `div`, just before the `nav` closing tag. Next, I've added div with `pull-right` class just before `button` in `navbar-header`. Finally, add some margins so that login anchor would look same as menu:

```
#rightAnchor {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

*UPDATE:* I did not check how it behaves when we have different resolution. How about this: we create 2 login anchors and controll theirs appearance with media queries? With this HTML would look like this:

```
<header id="main-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div id="rightAnchorMobile" class="pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Login</a>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>                 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Logo" src=""/></a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <div id="rightAnchor" class="pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Login</a>
                </div>
                <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="~/Home">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">link2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">link3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">link4</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>sublink</li>
                            <li>sublink2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>   
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {   
    #rightAnchorMobile {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #rightAnchor {
        display: none;
    }    
}

#rightAnchorMobile > a {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#rightAnchor > a {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you kamil. It solved half of my problem, it becomes on the right, if menu collapsed, but when in a large resolution, it stays near the logo (The closing div was a paste problem).